# How to click a button programmatically in Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I have a Button on my app screen and I want to test its functionality in various test cases by programmatically invoking the click event. For Windows Phone SDK there is no button1.PerformClick() that I can call. I am getting the button by traversing the Visual Tree; so, I have no access to the event handler subscribed to the Click event of that button. I need to somehow get the event handler delegate, subscribed to the event and then invoke that event handler like this eventHandler.Invoke(button, EventArgs.Empty).

Does anyone know how I can get the event handler delegate?

Comment: Do you really need to test the button click itself or would it be ok to have the event handler's only respectability is to call another function that performs the work and you can just directly call the 2nd function during the test.

Comment: I need to test the flow of the app and this button is a blocker! I can only have access to the UI elements that I get through VisualTreeHelper.

Comment: Can you explain why you're trying to do this? It sounds as though you've got code on a page (that will walk the visual tree) but it is unable to access the specifics of the page. Is the button on a dynamically generated control? Are you using a test framework of some sort? or trying to write your own?

Comment: Imagine there are some pages in an app that you can navigate to using buttons on the screen. The event handler for the click button takes care of these navigations. I want to test the flow of the app by invoking the click events, while not directly invoking the event handlers because those are private to me. I can't make any changes to the application being tested. So, the only way remains is getting  the event handler assigned to click event using the instance of the button that I get from the visual tree. Button is not dynamically generated.

Comment: Maybe it would be better to change my question to how I can get the event handler subscribed to an event of a UI element.